# Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While exporting render inline HTML by using phantomjs. It's throwing error `Your template was not saved as valid UTF-8` in ruby on rails. See screenshot of error message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFsj6.png)

Answer (score 1):

Find the exact match as per your problem below,

1. First, check the encoding of your Text editor.

If you are using Sublime, then go to `Preferences > Setting` - Default
    check for this  `show_encoding: false`

2. You can check it in Ruby also. Goto irb,

   `$string = 'demo'`

   `$string.encoding`

Make sure this must return `#<Encoding:UTF-8>` (only for your case)

3. If you are using pry gem, Then add binding.pry in your view. And when control comes to the template, hit the same command above to check encoding.
4. If above all are not satisfying then, Add

   ```
   encoding: < utf-8 >
   ```

at the top of your template